# How to update Form Control Caption in a protected worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form control which I wanted its caption changes between two entries. The worksheet is protected, but even I am changing `userinterfaceonly = true` and allowing `drawingobjects = true` it still can not be changed! is this a bug or I am doing something wrong? I am trying to avoid uprotect ==> modify ==> protect workaround.

```
Sub ShowChangesOnly()
Dim ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, Criteria As Range, Btn As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tod")
    ws.Protect , True, , , True, , , , , , , , , True, True
    Set Btn = ws.Buttons("Button 1")
    Set Rng = ws.Range("TodayD")
    Set Criteria = ws.Range("Criteria")
    RemoveFilters ws
    If Btn.Caption = "Filter Changes" Then
        Rng.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, Criteria
        Btn.Caption = "Show All"
        MsgBox "Total of " & Rng.Columns(3).SpecialCells(12).Count - 1 &  _
          " Found as Having Changes."
        Else
            Btn.Caption = "Filter Changes"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
M

Comment: What does `RemoveFilters` do?  Do you want drawing objects to be false,  `True to protect shapes. The default value is True.`

Comment: This is calling a procedure to remove all the filters in the worksheet and its listobjects if any. It is one of my general codes. Let me try with FALSE for the Objects, maybe thats why.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes, exactly that was the problem, I tricked by following items, which all was allow type, so I assumed this also should mean allow object changes.you can add it as answer, so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want drawing objects to be false,

From help : `True to protect shapes. The default value is True.`